# Safest way to pass access token from webview to react native application?

Tags: reactjs, webview, react-native

Situation:

The first application, react native, providing a webview of the second application.

The second application, a web application.

Through the first app, the user is already logged in. Now, instead of having them log in again on the webview, their access token is simply send to the second application, and they're automatically logged in with their access token (Jason Web Token). What is the best way to obfuscate this access token from anyone trying to grab it and use it in a malicious way (like a replay attack) and still get it to the second application?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this 2 years ago?

Comment: @dentemm We used URL query parameters to pass the token through HTTPS, which is secure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is comprehensive guide on how to send data to and from React Native WebView.

https://medium.com/@azharuddin31/react-native-pass-data-to-webview-and-get-data-out-of-webview-792ffbe7eb75

Thanks